# Database ERD - determining if food is a health risk

Tags: database, erd

Can anyone help me in constructing a good erd structure for determining health risks.

Say i have both recipe and ingredients table which have id as pk's and fk's on a 3rd table which i use for displaying.

How would i construct tables for the ingredients that would determine their nutritions.

Ingredient(table) -> Nutrition(table)

for comparing, lets say i am a user with diabetes so i am not allowed to eat dishes with too much sugar. I would then need to get all the ingredients of that dish and get the ones with sugar content and calculate how much sugar is there in total and determine if its okay or not.

Regarding of my approach, how would i construct the tables for nutrition. say It has the id of ingredients as its FK.

should i use the id as fk? or the name. and on my ingredient table, make the column of name as unique. Since id is auto increment so if someone inserts another recipe with egg and there is already a recipe with egg. it would create 2 rows of eggs in my ingredients table connected to two different recipes. So ingredient name would be best right?

Nutrition
ingredient id(fk) or ingredient name(fk)
nutrition(string)

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; there is a better forum, [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am completely unaware there was a separate one for database related topics.